# Ubuntu 20.04 failing to shutdown after latest update

Tags: shutdown

So I updated Ubuntu today via the Software Updates program and now when shutting down it gets stuck at

`[183.020379] systemd-udevd[410]: 000:04:00,7: Worker [458] failed`

Is there anything I can do to fix it and have it shut down normally?

Answer (score 1):

In my case Ubuntu upgraded my kernel from `5.11.0.-46` to `5.13.0-27` and then my laptop wouldn't shutdown, restart or wake up properly. I found out that if I choose to boot my computer using my previous kernel using "Grub Advanced Options" it works again, so it must be a kernel issue.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for an earlier error. Meant to say I upgraded from Ubuntu 20.04 to 21.10 after a kernel update to the newly released 5.13.0-28-generic (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-hwe-5.13/+bug/1958519).
Now restart and shutdown work, but suspend freezes completely, requiring long hard power button press into power off!

Comment: How is this an answer?